Blank screen hang on bootup with Ryzen 7840U iGPU with Noble
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2077266 for the issue details and upvote the bug if you're affected too.
Pasting the bug description here:
TLDR - Looks like the amdgpu module is included in the Jammy kernel images but not in Noble.
Hello!
I have a laptop with the AMD Ryzen 7840U CPU which has a 780M iGPU running both Jammy-based and Noble-based distro elementary OS releases.
This issue occurs only with the Noble and not Jammy edition.
Upon bootup with the quiet splash params there is just a blank screen and apparent hang which is prevented if I remove the splash option and then I get the expected login screen just fine.
Note that I ran the following command on both Jammy and Noble:
sudo lsinitramfs /boot/initrd-6.8xxxxx | grep amdgpu
And I see the amdgpu module is present in the Jammy image but not the Noble image.
So I appended amdgpu to the /etc/initramfs-tools/modules file and did:
sudo update-initramfs -uk all
Which resolves the issue for me with Noble as well.
Note both my Jammy and Noble installs are on the same kernel version currently 6.8-xxx-40 although the amdgpu module is included in the Jammy image but not the Noble one.
Thank you!
PS: I guess I want to ask whether others are facing this issue and do you see the same with stock Ubuntu Jammy and Noble ISOs?
